# Maya UV per local polygon triangle

Tags: c++, uv-mapping, maya-api

I was wondering if anyone has good way in Maya C++ Api to find a UV coordinate per local-relative triangle for polygon. Seems easy to find the per poly face UVs but how can I map them back to the poly triangles ?

Thanks